# How to compile a file in "Expect"?

Tags: expect

I am using a user interface menu which is using Expect files to display messages. In an attempt to add a menu item I had to change one of these file, however, it seems to me that the changes are not getting reflected. Do we need to compile this file?

Comment: Please provide some more details as to how the system is set up. You altered a file, so what did you change and how did it look like before. Perhaps we can then be of assistance.

As answered by Colin Macleod expect uses an interpreter, so there's no need for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

[Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) uses an interpreter for its scripts, there's no need to compile them.  If your change is not producing the result you want you should post details of the code.